# How to add a category to a drop down menu without using select and option HTML tags by manipulating the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I want to add a category/restaurant to my drop down menu by typing a value into an input field. As you can see in my code, I am not using the `<select>` and `<option>`. When I add my JS code it gets an error:

> TypeError: newRestaurant.add is not a function.

But when I changed the tags to `<select>` and `<option>` my JS code with the `add()` method worked.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="locationSetter">WHERE ARE YOU?</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><span>1</span></li>
        <li><span>2</span></li>
        <li><span>3</span></li>
        <li><span>4</span></li>
        <li><span>5</span></li>
        <li><span>6</span></li>
        <li><span>7</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Drop Down function and adding the chosen location to the location setter

const locationSetter = document.querySelector('.locationSetter');
const dropdownContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
const locations = document.querySelector('span');

dropdownContent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    locationSetter.textContent = e.target.innerHTML;
    locationSetter.style.color = 'blue';
    locationSetter.style.fontSize = '18px';
  }
});

// Adding a restaurant to the drop down menu
const addRestaurantInput = document.querySelector('.addRestaurantInput');

const restaurantListGenerator = newRestaurant => {
  const html = `<li><span>${newRestaurant}</span></li>`;

  //dropdownContent.innerHTML += html;
}

addRestaurantInput.addEventListener('submit', e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  const newRestaurant = addRestaurantInput.addnew.value.trim();

  let option = document.createElement('span');
  option.text = newRestaurant;
  dropdownContent.add(option, dropdownContent[0]);

  if (addRestaurantInput.length) {
    restaurantListGenerator(addRestaurantInput);
    addRestaurantInput.reset();
  }
})
```

I would like to figure out if I can make the JS code work and I can add a restaurant/ value which has been typed into the input field using `<ul>` and `<li>` tag.

Currently I only work in Vanilla JS.
Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `appendChild` instead of `add` and remove the second parameter. `add` is only for `select` element. See here: [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: Thanks, it worked out!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="locationSetter">WHERE ARE YOU?</button>
    <input type="text" class="addRestaurantInput"/>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><span>1</span></li>
        <li><span>2</span></li>
        <li><span>3</span></li>
        <li><span>4</span></li>
        <li><span>5</span></li>
        <li><span>6</span></li>
        <li><span>7</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
<script>
const locationSetter = document.querySelector('.locationSetter');
const dropdownContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
const locations = document.querySelector('span');
dropdownContent.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
    locationSetter.textContent = e.target.innerHTML;
    locationSetter.style.color = 'blue';
    locationSetter.style.fontSize = '18px';
  }
});

// Adding a restaurant to the drop down menu
const addRestaurantInput = document.querySelector('.addRestaurantInput');

//const restaurantListGenerator = newRestaurant => {
 // const html = `<li><span>${newRestaurant}</span></li>`;

  //dropdownContent.innerHTML += html;
//}

addRestaurantInput.addEventListener('change', e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  const newRestaurant = e.target.value;
  let elem = document.createElement("LI");
  let span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  let text = document.createTextNode(newRestaurant.toString());
   span.appendChild(text);
   elem.appendChild(span);

  dropdownContent.appendChild(elem);
})
</script>
</html>
```

You just have to append the child in the ul element just by getting value from element when the input value is change.Just enter the value in input and press enter. It will append the value in list. 
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I have slightly another solution using appendChild but will look into your example too. Thanks